# How to properly load WASM modules using Karma?

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, karma-runner, webassembly

I am working on a TypeScript library (let's call it `myLib`) that has a dependency on a `npm` package (let's call it `@mypackage/lib`) that then uses a `.wasm` file. Basically in my code I just import this lib and use it like this:

```
import * as Wasm from '@mypackage/lib';
export function doSomething(): string => Wasm.do_something();
```

When installing `@mypackage/lib`, the `.wasm` file is already present under `node_modules/@mypackage/lib`, so there's no need to compile it.

I created a sample web app using `webpack` for testing `myLib`. It contains the `index.ts` file:

```
import { doSomething } from 'myLib'
const v = doSomething();
console.log(v);
```

and a `bootstrap.js` file that loads `index.ts`:

```
import('./index.ts')
  .catch(e => console.error("Error importing `index.ts`:", e));
```

On this sample app, everything works without any issues.

Now, I want to write tests using Karma and mocha. I can't just test using mocha and nodejs because the `.wasm` from `@mypackage/lib` was compiled to run on the browser. The problem is that when trying to run the same `doSomething()` function under Karma, I get the following exception:

```
TypeError: wasm.__wbindgen_add_to_stack_pointer is not a function
```

The only resource I could find about Karma + WASM is [this link](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware/issues/229), which didn't help.
I also found [this project](https://github.com/libsbmljs/libsbmljs) which uses Karma to run tests that apparently call functions from a WASM object, but I cannot make any sense of how this is working. Looking at the tests, it appears the object coming from the WASM file is global, but I don't see how this would make a difference.

This is my `karma.conf.js` file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'karma-typescript'],
    files: [
      'spec/**/*.ts',
      'src/**/*.ts'
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      '**/*.ts': ['karma-typescript']
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'karma-typescript'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    karmaTypescriptConfig: {
      compilerOptions: {
        module: 'CommonJS',
        target: 'ES6',
        declaration: true,
        sourceMap: true,
        strict: true,
        moduleResolution: 'node',
      },
      exclude: [
        'dist',
        'node_modules'
      ],
      bundlerOptions: {
        transforms: [require("karma-typescript-es6-transform")({
          presets: [require("@babel/preset-env")],
          plugins: ["@babel/transform-runtime"]
      })],
      }
    },
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

And these are my current dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.15.8",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.22",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.9.2",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "karma": "^6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-typescript": "^5.5.2",
    "karma-typescript-es6-transform": "^5.5.2",
    "mocha": "^9.1.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just create a temp dir in karma tests dir and copy the wasm file to it. Add the wasm file path to karma config's `files` and `proxies`.